# Unity animation events

Tags: events, animation, synchronization, unity-game-engine

I have an animation and I want to show several time hints at certain points.

What is the best way of doing that?

I tried to make events in animation.. and call function which should notify the main GUI class, that something changed, but I am not sure if it is a good solution.
(actually I do not know how to do it effectively).

Or I can make a loop in my main GUI class, just reacting to time.. but I am not sure if the synchronization will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a cutscene like animation, I would use these animation events. This way it is easy to edit it later, if something changes in the animation. If you calculate seconds in the code while playing the animation, it will be a maintenance hell.

Comment: Yes, it should be a short animation playing in loop.

Comment: And when I want to use animator controller instead?